Visual Studio 2022 feature "Goto Definition" broken after using MVVM Toolkits Code Generators
it's about Visual Studio 2022 with a Desktop WPF App using MVVM Toolkit.
After adding a Class that uses Code Generators like ObservableObject VS does not navigate to the source code any more when using F12 Goto Definiton but instead navigates to Generated Class.
This is correct, but not very helpful while coding. Is it possible to change the behavior so that VS navigates to the SourceCode?
Sometimes VS opens the delcarations view instead of going to the pre-generated code.
Peek definitions sometimes does just shows an error.
F12 often just navigates to the generated code.
I tried the Options but did not find anything ignoring the Generated Code.
I would expect to have an option not to navigate to certai code.

IMHO, that's the expected behavior. Since the generated properties and commands only exist in the generated part of the class, it doesn't make any sense to navigate to "your" part of the class if it doesn't contain the symbol you're trying to navigate to. Visual Studio simply navigates to the file that contains the symbol you selected. Code generators are part of the Roslyn compiler platform and not part of VS, so I don't think that VS has a way to know that you want to navigate to "your" part of the class.

Partial properties (https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/3412) would be a nice solution to this -- please upvote that

@canton7 That wouldn't change the problem that VS doesn't have control over the source generator implementation. The CommunityToolkit.Mvvm source generators are implemented the way they are now and changing them to use partial properties would lead to more instead of less boilerplate code. While I agree that partial properties seem useful, this isn't a great use case, IMHO.

I agree that this is expected, I was hoping for a way to filter the resources for the navigation features - like "exclude" some part of the project for Open Declaration.

@Julian The point is, with partial properties, the definition of the property is in user-authored code and not in generated code. So this would fix the use-case in the question.

I know, but the use case here focuses on Visual Studio, while the source generators are independent from the IDE. Libraries (and code in general) shouldn't be written to make IDEs more convenient to use.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
